# SSIS merge join to update or delete rows locked forever

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I follow this blog post to create ssis package for transferring data between 2 tables. http://radacad.com/insert-update-and-delete-destination-table-with-ssis.

- Insert rows: not isnull(source_id) and isnull(dest_id)
- Delete rows: isnull(source_id) and not isnull(dest_id)
- Update rows: source_id = dest_id and source_row_version <> dest_row_version
  [image]

It works well with few records. However, when there are a lot of update and delete rows detected (thousand or hundreds of thousand rows). It run very slow, destination table get locked and job never done. another thing, this approach delete and update row by row.

Could you please help me overcome table lock in this case. Is there any way so that we can update or delete batch of rows instead of doing row by row?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a staging area, and use Execute SQL tasks to run SQL or execute stored procedures to carry out bulk operations based on comparing your staging area to your destination.

I realise this isn't a very satisfying answer if you were hoping to do everything in SSIS, but using blocking transformations ([MERGE JOIN is semi-blocking](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/jorg_klein/archive/2008/02/12/ssis-lookup-transformation-is-case-sensitive.aspx)), and row-by-row OLE command transforms generally won't scale well to large amounts of data.

Comment: Agreed.  Don't use that pattern. Two issues.  First, OLE DB Commands are making one database round trip per row. Very slow.  Second, we have two OLE DB Commands roundtripping the same table. Lock Central.  As Jo suggested, replace those OLE DB Commands with OLE DB Destinations.  Tie those destinations to delete and update staging tables. Then, on the Control Flow, after this Dataflow, add two EXECUTE SQL commands.  One to UPDATE FROM stage and another to DELETE FROM to stage.  This will be much faster.   Also before the dataflow add TRUNCATE stage table commands to keep stage lean.  Good luck!